# How to insert all the rows in a postgresql tabel to a kivy label as text?

Tags: python, postgresql, kivy, kivy-language

I have a table with 21 rows which is known as expences. I want to insert all the rows in the table to a kivy label as text. But it shows only the last row. I wasted hours on this. But I was unable to find a solution. Can i add a label for each row with a underline. What can i do for it?

This is a part of the code in the py file.

```
q_e_n = "select count(*) from expences where month="+"'"+month+"'"+";"
q_e = "select index, date, details, amount from expences where month="+"'"+month+"'"+";"

cursor.execute(q_e_n)
e_n, = cursor.fetchone()

cursor.execute(q_e)
expences = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.execute("commit;")

Builder.load_file('total_wealth.kv')

class Money_Manager(App, FloatLayout):
    fulldate = StringProperty()
    total_income = StringProperty()
    total_expences = StringProperty()
    cash = StringProperty()
    savings = StringProperty()
    t_w = StringProperty()
    index = StringProperty()
    date = StringProperty()
    details = StringProperty()
    amount = StringProperty()
    index2= NumericProperty()

    def build(self):
        i = 1
        for row in expences:
            index_amount = str(i)
            date_amount = str(row[1])
            details_amount = str(row[2])
            amount_amount =  str(row[3])


            i = i+1        


            self.index = index_amount
            self.date = date_amount
            self.details = details_amount
            self.amount = amount_amount

        self.fulldate = (month+", "+date)
        self.total_income = str(total_income_amount)
        self.total_expences = str(total_expences_amount)
        self.cash = str(cash_amount)
        self.savings = str(savings_amount)
        self.t_w = str(cash_amount+savings_amount)   

        return self


Money_Manager().run()
```

This is the code in the kv file.

```
ScrollView:
    size_hint: (.4,.6)
    do_scroll_x: False
    do_scroll_y: True
    pos: 30,30


    Label:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        text: app.index+")   "+app.date+"    "+app.details+"    "+app.amount +'\n'
        haligh: 'left'
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time a row is processed in your `for row in expences:` loop, You are replacing the values of `self.date` and the others, So only the last change gets displayed.

Perhaps using just one `StringProperty` for the `Label` `text` would make more sense.

```
class Money_Manager(App, FloatLayout):
    label_text = StringProperty('')
```

and in your loop, do something like:

```
self.label_text += index_amount + ')   ' + date_amount + '\n'
```

Then the reference in your `kv` could just be:

```
Label:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    text: app.label_text
    haligh: 'left'
```